# Internal user login into community

Tags: community, customer-community

How can i login standard user into community and redirect too my custom VF Page . I can use Global Header functionality but i don't redirect user from here to my custom VF page . global Header Redirect user to page which  user last viewed in community. how can i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question correctly. So you want to redirect a community user to a VF page?

One thing what I did for one of my recent projects is to create a Tab (in this case "Player Dash Board") for my Visualforce page that I want the user to land on, instead of the Home page. Then in the Community setup I removed all the other tabs. You could have the other tabs in there, but the Community loads the first one that is there in the below list.
[image]

Comment: i already do this before the problem first time it open the given tab but if you redirect to some chatter page and some user profile page next time it redirect to those last visited page this tab thing not work all time

Comment: This will work provided there are no parameters in the URL. If the user is logging in by clicking some link with an id then it will redirect to that page after login. Do you want even then that the user should redirect to your VF page? Perhaps you should explain your scenario a bit more clearly.

Comment: if you come into community from global header then it redirect you to the last page which you visited in community.may be its some user profile page, chatter home page or any other page . we cannot control this functionality. but i want every time user select from global header it redirect to my Custom Vf page tab which is the problem .

Comment: any body knows the answer??

Comment: @TusharSharma I tried your scenario and it happened to me as well. I think you should raise a case with Salesforce and get it clarified.

Comment: do you know any other solution