# Logging into Community through Global Header does not direct user to Community Homepage

Tags: community, customer-community

I’m running into a similar issue as this one posted previous, but has no resolution: [Internal user login into community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56034/internal-user-login-into-community)

When I login to the community as an internal user (with system admin profile, in full sandbox) via the global header, it's redirecting me to {community prefix}/home/showAllTabs.jsp instead of the VF Page that I setup for the community home page. This page results in an insufficient privileges error, which is caused by this page showing the salesforce homepage, so the user does not have access to the internal messages, recent items, chatter feed etc (since we are now logged into community). This really needs to direct the user to the community homepage that is setup.

Something interesting I noticed, if I login to the community and arrive at /home/showAllTabs.jsp as described above. Then change the url to {community prefix}/ or any other community page, it then works correctly. I can then log out, and then back into the community and it directs me to the community home. It'll work like this for about an hour, then it'll start directing me back to /home/showAllTabs.jsp.

I have this setup in a developer sandbox and it works perfectly there. When comparing both orgs all the site/community/profile settings are exact (other than org specific differences).

Anyone run into this before and have ideas on how to solve? Thanks!